# c# checkboxes verify state

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C#, i'm trying to get the state of a checkbox. I`ve done :

```
foreach (Control ctr in newProject.Controls) {
                if (ctr is CheckBox && ctr.Name.Contains("engine")) {

                }
            }
```

ctr.Checked doesn`t work obviously, how can I verify the state of ctr when ctr is a checkbox ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've verified that it is a checkbox, you can cast to the right type, and read the `Checked` property:

```
foreach (Control ctr in newProject.Controls) {
            if (ctr is CheckBox && ctr.Name.Contains("engine") 
                    && ((CheckBox)ctr).Checked) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var checkBoxes = newProject.Controls
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("engine"))
    .ToList();

foreach(var cb in checkBoxes)
{
    if (cb.Checked)
        // rest of your code...
}
```

If you're only interested in the checked ones, use:

```
var checkBoxes = newProject.Controls
    .OfType<CheckBox>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("engine") && x.Checked)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ is the answer to everything! :-)

Comment: isn't the cast `((CheckBox) cb)` superfluous?

Comment: Yes, in the case where you do `.OfType<CheckBox>()` as above, there is no need to do the coercion. So I'll take it out, thx!

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast it to a checkbox first.

```
 CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ctr;
 // Now you can do this: chk.Checked
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox has an ID, such as checkBox1. You can access the checkbox control directly using that ID.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the best answer!

Comment: was looping trough controls, with a lot of checkboxes, verifying each checkbox separately was not the purpose of the question